# $wpdb query not working in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to do a reviews plugin in Wordpress, and one of the thing that my client asked me to do was that a user should be able to rate only one product every 24 horas, so I have to establish a limit between rates.

And I made this function to check if the limit is reached:

```
function isAllowedToRate(){

        global $wpdb;
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $userId = get_current_user_id();
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'esvn_reviews';
        $isAllowed = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "
                SELECT user_id, fecha_calificacion 
                FROM {$table_name}
                WHERE user_id = {$userId} 
                    AND review_date = {$currentDate}
                "
            );

        if( count( $isAllowed > 0 ) ){

            return false;

        }else{

            return true;
        }

    }
```

But every time I try to run it, it returns false, the error that I'm getting from Wordpress is this:

```
 <div id='error'>
            <p class='wpdberror'><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> []<br />
            <code>
            SELECT user_id, fecha_calificacion 
            FROM wp_esvn_reviews
            WHERE user_id = 6 
                AND fecha_calificacion = 2015-10-30
            </code></p>
            </div>
```

If I take the same SQL and run it directly into the database, it works like a charm, but I keep getting this error from Wordpress and the function always returns false.

Comment: `AND fecha_calificacion = 2015-10-30` – you’re actually doing a _calculation_ here … http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: @CBroe it's not doing a calculation, the value needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you meant... it's doing arithmetic on the value rather than treating it as a date string.

Comment: I tested it with quotes and it didn't work, then I removed the quotes and post the code here, so it's not the quotes :S, I tried escaping the value like this too fecha_calificacion = '" . $date . "' and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error (in case someone needs the information in the future), I was treating $isAllowed as an array, and it was an object, I had to add ARRAY_A to the get_results:

```
$isAllowed = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "
                SELECT user_id, fecha_calificacion 
                FROM {$table_name}
                WHERE user_id = {$userId} 
                    AND review_date = {$currentDate}
                ",ARRAY_A /* output as an associative array */
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your date in single quotes.

```
    $isAllowed = $wpdb->get_results( 
            "
            SELECT user_id, fecha_calificacion 
            FROM {$table_name}
            WHERE user_id = {$userId} 
                AND review_date = '{$currentDate}'
            "
        );
```

Alternatively you could use `$wpdb->prepare()`, which I would consider better form.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT user_id, fecha_calificacion 
    FROM {$table_name} 
    WHERE 
      user_id = %d -- this is formatted as a (d)igit
      AND review_date = %s -- this is formatted as a (s)tring
SQL;
$isAllowed = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, $userId, $currentDate));
```

Comment: I tried the both ways you sujested, and neither worked. And wordpress doesn't help me very much with the error, it keeps showing me that error that I posted in the message, but now with quotes.